# If a web page doesn't exist, what headers should I return?

Tags: php, http

What should happen when a page doesn't exist on your site? If I have a custom error page set up in my .htaccess, I get a 302 temporary redirect to my 404 page (where I send 404 headers). Is this how it should work? Or should I do a 301 permanent redirect to the error page? I'm using php and Apache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-existent page has not "temporarily moved" (301) or "permanently moved" (302) to a page about the file not existing, it doesn't exist. The correct header to send is a 404, not anything else.

Don't redirect anywhere, instead serve your "file not found" page content at the URL that was requested.

Comment: But my pages are dynamically generated (sorry forgot to mention that), so I need to load the page to check if its a valid page and thus cant redirect from my .htaccess file right?

Comment: You can send a 404 (or other) header from PHP too, using `header()`.

Comment: So you must be rewriting all URLs to your PHP file that generates your page. That PHP file can, if it can't find the content to serve, send a 404 header and some "page not found" text. See GolezTrol's later answer for an example.

Comment: Yes well I did think it should just be a 404 but I was watching the headers of a couple of sites and they did redirects before showing a 404. Thanks though. I'm just going to include the error page and sending a 404 header in place of any content if the page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

If it never existed, you should send `404 Not Found`.

If it used to exist, but doesn't any more, you should send `410 Gone`.

Set up your server to send the error response directly.

You shouldn't redirect to an error page. That essentially means the conversation would go:

- Browser: Can I have /foo?
- Server: You can find /foo at /bar!
- Browser: Can I have /bar then?
- Server: I can't find /bar.

Bait and switch is never nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a static error page, say 404.html, that apache shows when a page is not found, and you need to be able to serve 404 pages for your dynamic pages as well, you can do that by sending the 404 header from PHP and feed the error page as well:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
readfile("404.html");
?>
```